# PHP how to merge arrays and create keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a custom Single elimination bracket which has to automatically check for results and make a create a round based on results. I can successfully check the results and save the teams in array for the next round but my problem is that it creates a strange array:

```
    foreach ($competitors as $competitor) {
                    $teams = array();

                    if ($competitor['scoreHome'] > $competitor['scoreAway']) {
                        $teams = array(array('home'=>$competitor['home']));
                    } 

                    if ($competitor['scoreHome'] < $competitor['scoreAway'] ) {
                        $teams = array(array('away'=>$competitor['away']));
                    }
    }               
                    print_r($teams);
```

OUTPUT:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [away] => testis5
        )

    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [home] => wdefgr
        )

    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [away] => testis4
        )

    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [home] => team1
        )

    )
```

What I need is to reindex this array and make `array_chunk($teams, 2)` so I can then save the information to a database and make this process again until the whole tournament is covered.

Output that I want:

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [teamName] => testis1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [teamName] => testis5
                )

            )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [teamName] => wdefgr
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [teamName] => testis2
            )

    )
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you show exactly what your intended output would look like?

Comment: Yes I just edited the question

Comment: What about ties? you check `>` and `<`, but that leaves `=`.

Comment: Your `$teams` value is overwritten on each iteration.

Comment: No in this tournament the ties are not an option

Comment: so how can I make it so it's not overwritten?

Comment: You can just append the value to the array with `$teams[]` instead of `$teams`. This will add an item instead of overwriting the variable

Comment: Oh of course, I'm such a dumbass haha :)

Comment: But still all the indexes are 0

Comment: Then use `$teams = array_values($teams);`

Comment: nope still the same

Comment: What is the output after that?

Comment: It's messed up it makes indexes but it goes thru 4 times and it prints all kinds of stuff

Comment: one more question when I declare a new array should I also put $teams[]=..?

Comment: Your code does not seems related to the output that you want. you are using index home and away. And want output as teamname. You printing the array inside the loop. what the hell are you trying to do.

Comment: No that teamname is from another array I put it there just to show what output I want. teamname is replaced by home, away

Comment: SOLVED the problem awas in foreach because I screwed up and saved array within a loop. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
$teams = array();
foreach ($competitors as $competitor) {

  $match = array();
  /* fill this match with the info you want, eg. */
  $match[] = array(array('home'=>$competitor['home']));
  $match[] = array(array('away'=>$competitor['away']));

  $team[] = $match;
}               
print_r($teams);
```

I omitted the inner conditionals, because they aren't relevant to the answer, but you'll have to do what you have to do to fill in that inner info.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP).*

I played a little bit more with Octopus's answer (look below on comments) and tweaked the code so it works perfectly. The example in Octopus' answer showed one index too many so I came up with this:

```
    foreach ($competitors as $competitor) {

        if ($competitor['scoreHome'] > $competitor['scoreAway']) {
            $match[] = array('home'=>$competitor['home']);
        } 

        if ($competitor['scoreHome'] < $competitor['scoreAway'] ) {
            $match[] = array('away'=>$competitor['away']);
        }
    }

    $matches = array_chunk($match, 2);
    print_r($matches);
```

Explanation:

I just got rid of array declaration and added array_chunk to it so it's seen as a match.

Output:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [away] => testis5
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [home] => wdefgr
                    )

        )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [away] => testis4
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [home] => team1
                    )

            )

    )
```